# HADOOP configuration properties can be set by user by setter method

Tags: hadoop

can anybody tell what are the equivalent setter methods for hadoop configuration properties (set in *.xml files). Do all the properties have setter methods? can you guide me to a book where I can find this detail. I spent few hours, did some google search but no help. for ex. in the mapred-site.xml we can set **mapred.max.split.size**, and the equivalent command in the java class file inside the main method is **FileInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(job, 64)**;

so for ex. what is the equivalent command for io.sort.mb.

please bear with me, I am new to hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the Hadoop [JobConf](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html) and [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) class documentation.
It lists all the possible methods which you can use to set configuration from the code.

And whichever property is not defined in JobConf class method, you can set that using [set(key,value) method](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#set(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) like this :

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
 conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://server:hdfsport");
```